# Swap function for a char*

Tags: c, swap

I have the simple function below which swap two characters of an array of characters (s). However, I am getting a "Unhandled exception at 0x01151cd7 in Bla.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x011557a4." error. The two indexes (left and right) are within the limit of the array. What am I doing wrong?

```
void swap(char* s, int left, int right) {
    char tmp = s[left];
    s[left] = s[right];
    s[right] = tmp;
}

swap("ABC", 0, 1);
```

I am using VS2010 with unmanaged C/C++. Thanks!

Comment: "ABC" has the type `const char[4]`, which can be converted safely to a `const char*`. The conversion to simply `char*` is deprecated, but implicit.

Comment: Your compiler should be giving you a warning about a deprecated cast from `const char*` to `char*` here.  Listen to your compiler!

Comment: Also, you should use the `size_t` type to store array indices and offsets rather than an `int`.

Comment: Do keep in mind this is meaningless: "VS2010 with unmanaged C/C++". C/C++ is not a language, and VS2010 is a C++ compiler, not a C compiler.

Comment: @GMan Well VS2010 can compile C code too AFAIK...

Comment: @Alexandre: You'll have to define "can compile". Sure it can compile "some C code", but it's not a C compiler; the languages are different.

Comment: @GMan I don't know about 2010 but VC++ 2009 and earlier could compile real C89 code (not just the common C++ subset)

Comment: @Alexandre: I assume you mean 2008, there is no 2009. :) And you're right, I had heard 2010 cut off C, but it's still there. I will warn OP that C++ is the default, though, and that C support isn't nearly as much as C++ support.

Comment: @GMan You're right I meant VC9 which is 2008. I really doubt they'll ever cut off C support it's used a lot even if IDE support is not great. I'm still waiting for C99 though.

Comment: @Alexandre: Yeah, if they embraced C99 that would be awesome. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't modify a string literal. instead try this:

```
char s[] = "ABC"
swap(s, 0, 1);
printf("%s\n", s);
```

Comment: This is correct. Try using this code to call it:
    char swapStr[3] = "ABC";
    swap(swapStr,0,1)

Comment: @Dave: careful, your example doesn't have a NUL terminator, the buffer needs to be 4 chars big!

Comment: @Evan Well at least if you want the printf() to work. swap() doesn't mind

Comment: @GMan: I believe it is legal to have an array which is the size of all the characters in a string literal without the NUL (aka 3 for "ABC"). The character array is simply not NUL terminated (and therefore not really a "string"). But the code is legal so long as you don't operate on it as if it were a NUL terminated string.

Comment: @GMan: which particular version of the standard is that from? My copy of both the C89/C99 standards don't even have a section 8 (7 is the library reference, then come the annexes).

Comment: Ah, found it. C++ **8.5.2/2**. However, I believe that this is a divergence from C89/99 which has no such example.

Comment: @Evan: Oh, I'm an idiot. I completely assumed this question was C++, not C. You're right, of course. I'll delete my other comments. To conclude: `char a[3] = "ABC";` is ill-formed in C++, and well-formed in C (truncating.)

Comment: In addition, the C standard has 6.7.8/32 which uses `char s[] = "abc", t[3] = "abc";` as both legal examples of initializing a character array. and specifically says they are equivalent to: `char s[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', '\0' },
t[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c' };`

Answer (score 1):

"ABC" is in the RODATA section, so you can't change it, please see the assembly:

```
        .section        .rodata
.LC0:
        .string "ABC"
```